# Win 7 taskbar features

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I hover the mouse over an active task icon on the win7 taskbar, the miniature window appears momentarily and disappears, not allowing to click and maximise the task. Can this feature be controlled, to make the small window stay visible and allow selecting and maximizing the task?

Answer (score 1):

> Can this feature be controlled, to make the small window stay visible and allow selecting and maximizing the task?

Yup, it can be controlled in the following manner:

1. First when you hover over an icon in the taskbar area, it shows you a small miniature window, but you haven't gone there yet.
2. Further, when you hover inside that miniature window, then it will be enlarged and you will get a view of how that Window will look when maximized.
3. At this stage, if you actually click on that maximized view, then the window will be actually maximized and you will be transitioned there.

To give you an example, suppose I'm working in Notepad++ application which is currently open. Now, assume that Firefox is also running on my machine, I hover my mouse on the Firefox icon in the taskbar (stage-1). At this point, the screen will be something like this:

[image: Stage-1]

Now, I hover to the miniature-window of firefox (stage-2):

[image: Stage-2]

As you can see, firefox is actually seen in the background. At this point, if I click on the firefox window (stage-3), firefox will become active. Otherwise, if I hover back to Notepad++ view and click there, I'll be back to Notepad++!

Hope this concept is clear to you now.